# Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

so i coded a binary search tree in C which looks with this struct:

```
struct tnode {
    int content;
    struct tnode *left; /* left tree part */
    struct tnode *right; /* right tree part */
};
```

My main method:

```
int main() {

    struct tnode *Baum = NULL;
    struct tnode *tmpPos = NULL;
    Baum = addelement (Baum, 32);
    Baum = addelement(Baum, 50);
    Baum = addelement(Baum, 60);
    tmpPos = searchnode(Baum,50);
}
```

So basicly this creates me a Binary search tree with 3 elements (32,50,60). My searchnode method is supposed to move a pointer to the "50" so i can delete it afterwards. However my searchnode Method only returns the pointer if the element im searching is the root of my binary search tree.

searchnode:

```
struct tnode *searchnode(struct tnode *p, int nodtodelete) {
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("Baum ist leer oder Element nicht vorhanden \n");
    }

    if ( p -> content == nodtodelete) {
        return p;
    }

    if (p->content > nodtodelete) {
        searchnode (p->right, p->content);
    }
    if (p->content < nodtodelete) {
        searchnode(p->left, p->content);
    }
}
```

Maybe you guys can help me.

Comment: Don't you have the left/right subtree decisions reversed? `if (p->content > nodtodelete)` you should be taking the left path.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  Have you already confirmed that `addelement()` works correctly?

Comment: `searchnode` returns nothing in 3 of 4 `if`s.

Comment: addelement works correctly for sure

Comment: New Problem in the Answers if you can spot the mistake, i would appreciate it alot.

Comment: Please don't change the question after answers has been posted. Ask a new question if you have one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function has undefined behavior since it doesn't have any `return` statements in the recursive calls.

Also, the recursive calls need to be fixed to use the right input.

```
struct tnode *searchnode(struct tnode *p, int nodtodelete)
{
   if (p == NULL)
   {
      printf("Baum ist leer oder Element nicht vorhanden \n");
      return NULL;
   }

   if ( p -> content == nodtodelete)
   {
      return p;
   }

   // This is copied from OP's question but it seems suspect.
   // It should probably be:
   // if (p->content < nodtodelete)
   if (p->content > nodtodelete)
   {
      return searchnode (p->right, nodtodelete);
   }

   return searchnode(p->left, nodtodelete);
}
```

Comment: Posted an aswer with another question related to the Binary Search tree, maybe you can spot the mistake here aswell.

Comment: @RobinSchmidt, please post another question instead of asking another question in an answer.

Comment: @RSahu  -Is left/right decision reversed? -uh you commented that!

Comment: @WeatherVane, Yes, I think it is reversed.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the value you're searching for, not the value of the node:

```
searchnode (p->right, nodtodelete);
                      ^
```

Make the same change to the other recursive call.

```
searchnode(p->left, nodtodelete);
```